# Use WriteConcern in MongoCollection.deleteMany in mongo-java-driver 3.12

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver, mongo-collection

I am using mongo-java-driver-3.12.X version.
I want to change the deprecated API

```
DBCollection.remove(query, WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED);
```

to

```
MongoCollection.deleteMany(query)
```

1. Is there a way to specify WriteConcern?
2. What will be the default behaviour if WriteConcern is not specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find this information in the [driver documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/).

WriteConcern can be set to multiple level for 3.12 version it goes like this.

### MongoClient:

```java
MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().writeConcern(WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED).build();
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(
        new ServerAddress("host1", 27017),
        new ServerAddress("host1", 27018)), options);
```

or with a connection string

```java
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://host1:27017,host2:27017/?w=unacknowledged"));
```

### MongoDatabase

```java
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test").withWriteConcern(WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED);
```

### MongoCollection

This is the case you are interested in

```java
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("restaurants").withWriteConcern(WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED);
collection.deleteMany(query);
```

Keep in mind that MongoCollection and MongoDatabase are immutable so calling withWriteConcern create a new instance and has no effect on the original instance.

For the default behavior you need to check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) because it depends on your mongodb version.

Comment: ideally, one would expect the default `WriteConcern` to be what the `mongoClient` was initialized with...if not that, then what the driver's underneath default has been. I think its `WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED` to fallback upon.

Comment: MongoCollection.withWriteConcern(WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED) is what I wanted. Thanks.